# Add footnotes on both sides

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I need to add a two line text on the right side of the footnote, as well as the left side. 
Example:

```
ABC                                                   GHI
DEF                                                   JKL
```

But when I press enter after typing GHI, the JKL goes under DEF. I selected the basic footnote style to do that. I've tried changing indentation but it doesn't work. How can I fix it? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert Footnote (works for  Footer as well)

---

Using the Ruler create a Right Justified Tab at the line end for both lines.
Then after Delete any tabs not required ( drag away )

Type  appropriate [tabs] between "Text" and [enter] after 1st line.

This should not wrap around.